# Error ao fazer Login usando Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

Recentemente comecei a usar o Spring Security para fazer a segurança de minha aplicação, o problema é que quando clico no botão logar o correto era me levar até a página inicial da aplicação, porem ao clicar está me devolvendo um arquivo .js que está na pasta js, então clico para voltar a pagina anterior e clico em logar novamente e ele me leva para a página correta, isso já ocorreu com vocês? Vou adicionar as imagens do passo a passo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou colocar o código do login e do método que recebe a action e a configuração do Spring Security:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
 xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
 layout:decorator="LayoutPadrao">
<head>
<title>LogSys</title>
</head>

<section layout:fragment="conteudo">
 <body>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <div th:if="${param.error}">
     <div class="alert alert-danger">Usuário ou Senha inválidos!</div>
    </div>

    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
     <div class="alert alert-info">Até logo!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-info">
     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">ENTRE</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <form th:action="@{/entrar}" method="post">
       <div class="form-group">
        <input name="username" class="form-control"
         placeholder="Usuário" />
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"
         placeholder="Senha" />
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Entrar</button>
       </div>


      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Classe Configuração:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ImplementsUserDetailService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


    http.
    authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/entrar")
        .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        ;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**","/fonts/**","/images/**");
}
```

}

Método que recebe a request e retorna a página:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "/entrar")
    public String entrar() {
        return "Entrar";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, você tem que ignorar a pasta onde estão os scripts .js, acredito que isso resolva seu problema:

```
@Override 
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**","/fonts/**","/images/**"); 
}
```